# Unable to read repository at https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/composite/4.17.0/content.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss-tools, eclipse-marketplace

I wanted to install JBoss Tools plugin. I get the following error when I try to install from Eclipse MarketPlace.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you use a version of OpenJDK which supports your Eclipse version. It is very important and will impact successful loading of Eclipse.

For example, with Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0) you should use OpenJDK 11.0.2.

Comment: It'd be really helpful to include a link to the recommended versions / supported OpenJDK versions per Eclipse version.